# Mocking 3rd party api for rest api functional testing

Tags: java, unit-testing

I need to test the functionality of rest end point using Rest Template.
Below is the dummy rest api i need to test

```
@GetMapping(value = "/test")
public String getText(){
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String value = restTemplate.getForObject("EXTERNALURL/helloWorld",String.class);
    return value +" got the value";
}
```

I have the below test cases which hits the above rest end point

```
private void expectFixedData() {
    MockServerClient mockServerClient = ClientAndServer.startClientAndServer("127.0.0.1",1080);
    try {
        mockServerClient.when(HttpRequest.request().withMethod("GET")
                        .withPath("/helloWorld"), Times.exactly(1))
                .respond(HttpResponse.response().withStatusCode(200)
                        .withBody("{ 'incorrect username and password combination' }")
                        .withDelay(TimeUnit.SECONDS, 1));
    }
    finally{
        mockServerClient.close();
    }
}

@Test
public void callExternalService(){
    expectFixedData();
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String value = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/test",String.class);
    Assert.assertTrue(value.equals("incorrect username and password combination got the value"));
}
```

But when i run the test cases it still calls the external URL

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to mock response for 3rd party using WireMock